# Namespace Crossroads

Tags: vb.net, networking, namespaces, adapter

I'm a novice coder so I'm not that knowledgeable.  Please be kind with my silly questions.
I am writing an IP address switching utility

I've got two VB.NET functions:
GetNIC()  and  MakeStatic()

GetNIC() uses the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace.  I have it running to find the current IPv4 adapter, IP, DGW, SM and other info.

MakeStatic() uses the System.Management namespace.  I am trying to figure out how to use the info from GetNIC() to single out the same adapter and change the info.  Here is a snippet of my code to switch the IP.  I never really have used ManagementBaseObjects before and was wondering how to find the GUID (or something) that matches the GUID I have already found in GetNIC().

```
            Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
            Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
            Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing

            objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
            objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")

            'Set DefaultGateway
            objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {Gateway}
            objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

            'Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
            objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {IPAddress}
            objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {SubnetMask}

            objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
            objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)
```

Basically I'm shooting for:

```
If objMO.<<something>> = NICguid then
   <<<Do the above code>>
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!

```
objMO("MACAddress")
```

Thanks!